# jQuery - fails to work after page changes (FF & IE)

Tags: jquery, html, joomla

I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/

It works perfectly on Chrome, the scroll bar changes to my settings on every page.
However:

When in Firefox or IE(9), if I do a cache refresh then the scroll bar changes normally.  However as soon as I go to another page, or refresh, the scroll bar disappears and the default browser one is placed.

I also have another small Jira jQuery plugin which doesn't load, but works after a page cache refresh < everything works in chrome.

The website is on Joomla, with the following placed right before the  tag.

```
    <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='./ext/jquery-plugins/scrollpane/jquery.nicescroll.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(
    function() { 
    $("html").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor: "#cf4725",
        cursorwidth: 10,
        cursorborder: "1px solid #000000",
        mousescrollstep: 50
    });
});
</script>
```

Site is on www2.lethal-zone.eu for now.

Anyone got any suggestions as to what this is?

TL;DR: In FF & IE, jQuery works on page cache, but fails after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to swap $ for jQuery.  No idea why it worked on cache refresh though!

Comment: Joomla loads mootools and mootools takes the $, so depending on mootools being there or not your script would work or not.  But usually mootools will either load or not, so check your headers for duplicates and consistency you may have some cache corruption